# Invoke-Sqlcmd doesn't allow TrustServerCertificate

Tags: sql-server, powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I'm one of two SQL Server DBAs trying to use a PowerShell script and have run into a problem.  The code I'm trying to run is:

```
$DSQLServer = 'VM-SQL119'
$Results = Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $DSQLServer -Database master -Query "SELECT @@ServerName" -TrustServerCertificate
```

When I run it on my desktop, **it works**.  When the other DBA runs it, he gets:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'TrustServerCertificate'
```

Both our machines are running the same version of PowerShell:

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      19041  3570
```

I Googled how to find which module a cmdlet is coming from and, again, both our desktops return the same information:

```
(Get-Command -Name Invoke-sqlcmd).ModuleName
SqlServer
```

Can anyone shed some light on how the same command, in the same version of PowerShell, from the same module, can work on one machine and fail on the other?

Thanks in advance.

Ken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fundamentally** - unfortunately - **there are *two* - technically distinct - `Invoke-SqlCmd` cmdlets**:

- The ***obsolete*** [`Invoke-SqlCmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlps/invoke-sqlcmd) command from the **obsolete [`SQLPS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlps/) module**.
- The ***current*** [`Invoke-SqlCmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd) command from the ***successor* module, [`SQLServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/)**

See [SQL Server PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/sql-server-powershell) for background information.

---

However, since **you're *both* apparently using the modern `SQLServer` module**, the **difference comes down to what *version* of that module** you're using:

- From the [description of the `-TrustServerCertificate` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd#-trustservercertificate) (emphasis and direct link added):

> This parameter is **new in v22** of the module. For more details, see [Strict Connection Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/networking/tds-8?view=sql-server-ver16#strict-connection-encryption) under Related Links.

---

To **diagnose the problem**:

In a pristine session, run:

```
(Get-Command Invoke-SqlCmd).Module
```

which prints both the name and the version number of the (effective) module from which the `Invoke-SqlCmd` command originates, which the `Get-Command` call implicitly [auto-loads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules#module-auto-loading) in the process.

Note that both the obsolete `SqlPs` *and* the modern `SqlServer` module may be present, and for each there may be *multiple versions*.

That is why it is important to run the `Get-Command` call in a pristine session, i.e. one in which no third-party modules have been imported yet, given that code running in the session could explicitly import the *wrong* module or an *older version*, after which `Invoke-SqlCommand` then refers to *that* module's command.

`Get-Module -ListAvailable SqlServer, SqlPs` lists *all* versions of these two modules that are discoverable via auto-loading (i.e. via the directories listed in [`$env:PSModulePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Variables#powershell-environment-variables), in order). For a *given* module, the version listed *first* (if there are multiple) is the *effective* one, i.e. the one that will be auto-loaded.
With *two* modules in the picture, whichever('s first version) is listed first is the effective one.

It's best to **remove all obsolete versions** - note that you **may have to run *with elevation*** (as administrator) if the modules to be removed were installed with `-Scope AllUsers`:

- Remove *all* versions of the obsolete `SqlPs` module.

  ```
  # See below if that fails.
  Uninstall-Module -AllVersions SqlPs
  ```
- Remove *all but the latest* version of the `SqlServer` module.

  ```
  # E.g., to uninstall v21.0.17099
  # See below if that fails.
  Uninstall-Module -RequiredVersion 21.0.17099 SqlServer
  ```

If the use of [`Uninstall-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/uninstall-module) fails, despite running with elevation - usually because the target module wasn't installed with [`Install-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module) to begin with - *remove the underlying directories manually* - which again may require *elevation*:

- List the candidate set of module directories:

  ```
  (Get-Module -ListAvailable SqlPs, SqlServer).Path | Split-Path -Parent
  ```
- Identify those to delete and pass them to [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item) `-Recurse -Force`

  - Note: If a given directory path ends in a version number (e.g. `...\SqlServer\22.0.59`) and its parent directory (`...\SqlServer`) ends up *empty* after removal, you can remove the latter too.

---

The **latest version of the `SqlServer` module can be downloaded [from the PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer)**, i.e. can be installed with, e.g., [`Install-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module) `-Force SqlServer`.

Comment: We've found a few differences.  1) When I run "Get-Module SqlPS -ListAvailable", I see Version 1.0 installed but when my coworked runs that command, he gets nothing.  2) When I run "Get-Module SqlServer -ListAvailable", I see one version installed: 22.0.59.  When my coworker runs that same command he sees two versions installed: 20.0 (C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules) and 22.1.1 (C:\Users\<username>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules).  Think we need to uninstall the 20.0 version from his desktop?

Comment: @Ken, the `C:\Users\<username>` version should normally take precedence, but it can't hurt to remove the obsolete version as well as the obsolete `SqlPs` module. In a pristine session,  `(Get-Command Invoke-SqlCommand).Module` will tell you the name and version of the module that is in effect, i.e. the one that is auto-loaded when you invoke `Invoke-SqlCommand` (in fact, the `Get-Command` call itself triggers auto-loading).

Comment: @Ken, I've added instructions on how to remove unwanted modules / module versions to the answer.

Comment: thanks for including the reference to Remove-Item.  I needed that to get rid of SQLPS on my computer.

Comment: My coworker and I used the information provided to synchronize the PowerShell configuration on our machines and are now seeing the call to Invoke-Sqlcmd complete successfullly on both computers.  Thank you so much for your help.  I've marked your response as the answer.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Ken; my pleasure. Thanks for accepting.