# invoke-sqlcmd results are different based on the SqlServer module installed

Tags: sql-server, powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I'm running a PS script that is loading the `SqlServer` module and then calling `Invoke-SqlCmd`. The `Invoke-SqlCmd` is calling a script with stored procedure.

I originally developed the script using 21.1.18256. Everything is working, but v21.1.18256/`Invoke-SqlCmd` does not work with `-TrustServerCertificate`. I found out this option is not available in this version and so decide to upgrade to be able to use this parameter.

I then upgraded to v22.1.1. I tested and found that the `Invoke-SqlCmd` reacts differently in this version running the same stored procedure. Running the exact same script, the procedure does not work.

I ran it interactively and it see it calling the procedure and shows that it is working. I checked the database and found that no records were inserted.

I have a Try/Catch, Begin/End Tran in the SQL script. I removed the Begin/End Tran and the stored procedure reacted differently. Now it does the inserts as expected, but only partially. In a table that I'm expected 100 records, I'm only getting 25 records.

I've tried v22.0.59 and the results were the same as v22.1.1.  When I switch back to v21.1.18256, everything is working correctly and the record counts are as expected. I'm currently switching to native `sqlcmd.exe` and it is working as expected.

Not sure if anybody have seen this before or am I doing something incorrectly.

I'm on Windows 2019 / SQL Server 2019 / PS v5.1

Comment: Without seeing what your procedure does, and the table definitions, we cannot diagnose it. Unclear why the whole preamble about `TrustServerCertificate` is relevant to this. Anyway, it might just be as simple as some bad error handling combined with `XACT_ABORT` being on or off depending on version. But hard to say without seeing what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

See: [PowerShell: invoke-sqlcmd with Get-Credential doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51622424/powershell-invoke-sqlcmd-with-get-credential-doesnt-work)

And: [Invoke-Sqlcmd works on one desktop, fails on another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77449589/invoke-sqlcmd-works-on-one-desktop-fails-on-another)

These might address the issues you are having:

- Not all commands work correctly with `-Credential`
- Quoted: *"Fundamentally - unfortunately - there are two - technically distinct Invoke-SqlCmd cmdlets"*
- The obsolete Invoke-SqlCmd command from the obsolete **SQLPS** module.
- The current Invoke-SqlCmd command from the successor module, **SQLServer**

Install the correct SQL Server module here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35510547)

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze the answer is to just to use the correct version of the SQLserver module….not sure what you mean here.